# How do I set a variable in the install profile to enable users to sign up for the website

Tags: configuration

I am trying to understand about how setting variables works in install profiles. As an example, how would I set the option to enable people to create a website for the account in the install profile? Here is the page on variable_set https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set but how do I retrieve the value.

Comment: You don't know how to set variables in profile, which one to set, or how to retrieve it?

Comment: I don't know how to set, or how to find out which one to set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables in install profiles work no differently to variables in a 'normal' bootstrap.

To set a variable use [`variable_set()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7):

```
variable_set('var_name', 'value');
```

To retrieve it, use [`variable_get()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/7/search/variable_get):

```
$var = variable_get('var_name', 'default');
```

To find the names of variables, the easiest method is to install the Devel module and visit the variable editor at /devel/variable

Comment: How do you know what the var_name is ?

Comment: @AndrewWelch Just updated the answer - you either need to check the variables table (which you can do through the UI with Devel), or go through the code for the various admin forms that set those variables to find the name(s).

Answer (score 1):

Users can register at your Drupal 7 site by default but you have to disable that. If you want to do this, just put following in your profile.install file:

```
// Only administrators can create user accounts.
variable_set('user_register', USER_REGISTER_ADMINISTRATORS_ONLY);
```

It would make sense to copy the standard installation profile to have a good base and then you just could add these two lines from above :)